# No Instance of Overloaded function while using STL queues

Tags: c++

Okay so I have a programming project due in about 7 minutes. My project reads a double GPA and a string Name in a txt file. I correctly place the GPA and Names into separate STL lists for the project. My problem comes when I try to push the highest GPA value into a queue. At that point it gives the error that no instance of overloaded function.

Since I am using pointers, I have tried different methods of using pointers but to no avail. I figure that pointers might be a part of the problem.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list> 
#include <queue>

using namespace std;
//using std::because it says cout is ambiguous even with std included 

int main()
{
    double GPA;
    double highestGPA;
    string name;

    list<double> listGPA;                   //lists and their iterators    
    //list<double>::iterator ptrGPA, ptrHighestGPA;
    double *ptrGPA, *ptrHighestGPA;

    list<string> listName;
    //list<string>::iterator ptrName, ptrHighestName;
    string *ptrName, *ptrHighestName;

    queue<double> queueGPA; //queues
    //queueGPA.front() = 0;
    queue<string> queueName;
    //queueName.front() = "";

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("HighestGPAData.txt");          

    if (!infile)                  //if file doenst exist              
    {
        std::cout << "The input file does not "
             << "exist. Program terminates!"
             << endl;

        std::system("pause");
        return 1;

    }

    std::cout << fixed << showpoint;                
    std::cout << setprecision(2);                    

    infile >> GPA >> name;                      
    while (infile) {            //place contents of file into 2 STL lists
        listGPA.push_back(GPA);
        listName.push_back(name);
        infile >> GPA >> name;
    }

    std::cout << "\nSTL list for GPA:\n";
    for (auto g : listGPA) { //range based for loop that prints GPA list
        std::cout << g << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\nSTL list for names:\n";
    for (auto s : listName) { //range based for loop that prints name 
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
    std::system("pause");

    ptrGPA = &listGPA.front(); //initialize pointers for each list
    ptrHighestGPA = ptrGPA;

    ptrName = &listName.front();
    ptrHighestName = ptrName;


    while (!listGPA.empty()) // there are two lists (name and GPA) 
        if (ptrGPA > ptrHighestGPA) {

            while (!queueGPA.empty()) {     //destroy queue i (so a lower 
                queueGPA.pop();
            }

            while (!queueName.empty()) {    //destroy queue if a     higher //gpa is found (so a lower gpa is not printed)
                queueName.pop();
            }

            /***********************problem here */
            ptrHighestGPA = ptrGPA;  
            queueGPA.push(ptrHighestGPA);   //add to queue if it is 
            ptrHighestName = ptrName;
            queueName.push(ptrHighestName);

        }

        else if (ptrGPA == ptrHighestGPA) {  //add to the queue ifcurrent gpa 
        queueGPA.push(ptrHighestGPA);
        queueName.push(ptrHighestName);
        }
        /* end problem */
        listGPA.pop_front();
        listName.pop_front();

        ptrGPA++;
        ptrName++; //= listName.front();

    }

    while (!queueGPA.empty()) {         //print the largest gpa.
        std::cout << queueGPA.front() << " ";
        queueGPA.pop();
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    while (!queueName.empty()) {        //print who has the highest gpa
        std::cout << queueName.front() << " ";
        queueName.pop();
    }
    std::system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Currently it outputs both lists but I can easily comment that out. I want the queues queueName and queueGPA to contain the highest GPA and name associated with that GPA from the lists listGPA and listName.

Thank you guys

Comment: Please edit your question to include a full and complete copy-paste of the error output, including possible informational notes. Also please add a comment in the code you show where the errors are. And if possible, please try to minimize the code even more, a good [mcve] should be only big enough to replicate the problem you're asking about, not more. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: On an unrelated note, the "default" container should in almost all cases be `std::vector`.

Comment: The root of all your woes is the use of pointers. It looks like there is no reason to use them at all. And it's not clear at all why you're using queues.

Comment: A pointer is not the object it points to.

Comment: After the first iteration `ptrGPA > ptrHighestGPA` has undefined behaviour. You've destroyed the object they point to.